# How to extract content from a XML node using the tag name and not the index in Julia with EzXML.jl?

Tags: xml, julia

```
#=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <primates>
     <genus name="Homo">
         <species1 name="sapiens">Human</species>
     </genus>
    <genus name="Pan">
         <species1 name="paniscus">Bonobo</species>
        <species2 name="troglodytes">Chimpanzee</species>
     </genus>
 </primates>
=#
```

in order to get the content: "Chimpanzee" you will do it like

`elements(primates[2])[2].content`

but I need something like

`elements(primates[2])["species2"].content`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it via XPATH query:

```
julia> nodecontent.(findall("genus[2]/species2", primates))
1-element Vector{String}:
 "Chimpanzee"
```

Note that your XML was invalid so I needed to correct it for this example to work.

```
txt = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <primates>
    <genus name="Homo"><species1 name="sapiens">Human</species1></genus>
    <genus name="Pan">
        <species1 name="paniscus">Bonobo</species1>
        <species2 name="troglodytes">Chimpanzee</species2>
     </genus>
 </primates>"""

primates = root(EzXML.parsexml(txt));
```

Comment: Thank you.  would you recommend the package for working with XML in Julia?. This one seems pretty solid.

Comment: EzXML should be good. You could also have a look at LibExpat (it has not been updated for a while but the C library it is based on is quite solid)